# Google Maps V3 Polygon Drawing

Tags: google-maps

I don't know why I am getting colored certain area (see the picture). NOTE: When mouse is on this area it act's like it's out of polygon so polygon is not clickable there, but is still colored.

Data are under the picture.

[image]

```
var coord_region1 = [
{lat: 37, lng: 12},
{lat: 37, lng: 13},
{lat: 37, lng: 14},
{lat: 37, lng: 15},
{lat: 37, lng: 16},
{lat: 38, lng: 16},
{lat: 38, lng: 17},
{lat: 39, lng: 17},
{lat: 39, lng: 18},
{lat: 40, lng: 18},
{lat: 40, lng: 19},
{lat: 41, lng: 19},
{lat: 41, lng: 18},
{lat: 41, lng: 17},
{lat: 42, lng: 17},
{lat: 42, lng: 16},
{lat: 42, lng: 15},
{lat: 43, lng: 15},
{lat: 43, lng: 14},
{lat: 44, lng: 14},
{lat: 44, lng: 13},
{lat: 45, lng: 13},
{lat: 45, lng: 14},
{lat: 46, lng: 14},
{lat: 46, lng: 15},
{lat: 47, lng: 15},
{lat: 47, lng: 14},
{lat: 47, lng: 13},
{lat: 47, lng: 12},
{lat: 47, lng: 11},
{lat: 47, lng: 10},
{lat: 47, lng: 9},
{lat: 47, lng: 8},
{lat: 47, lng: 7},
{lat: 46, lng: 7},
{lat: 46, lng: 6},
{lat: 45, lng: 6},
{lat: 44, lng: 6},
{lat: 44, lng: 7},
{lat: 43, lng: 7},
{lat: 43, lng: 8},
{lat: 43, lng: 9},
{lat: 43, lng: 10},
{lat: 44, lng: 10},
{lat: 44, lng: 9},
{lat: 44, lng: 8},
{lat: 43, lng: 8},
{lat: 42, lng: 8},
{lat: 41, lng: 8},
{lat: 40, lng: 8},
{lat: 39, lng: 8},
{lat: 39, lng: 9},
{lat: 39, lng: 10},
{lat: 40, lng: 10},
{lat: 41, lng: 10},
{lat: 42, lng: 10},
{lat: 42, lng: 11},
{lat: 42, lng: 12},
{lat: 41, lng: 12},
{lat: 41, lng: 13},
{lat: 41, lng: 14},
{lat: 40, lng: 14},
{lat: 40, lng: 15},
{lat: 39, lng: 15},
{lat: 38, lng: 15},
{lat: 38, lng: 14},
{lat: 39, lng: 14},
{lat: 39, lng: 13},
{lat: 39, lng: 12},
{lat: 38, lng: 12},
{lat: 37, lng: 12},
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. The problem is for a polygon "hole" you need to define data like [path_outer, path_inner]. Important part is to have defined points in opposite direction than the outer path.

Like google documentation says:

```
    // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's  outer path.
    var outerCoords = [
      {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
      {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
      {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
    ];

    // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's inner path.
    // Note that the points forming the inner path are wound in the
    // opposite direction to those in the outer path, to form the hole.
    var innerCoords = [
      {lat: 28.745, lng: -70.579},
      {lat: 29.570, lng: -67.514},
      {lat: 27.339, lng: -66.668}
    ];
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-hole